# Repeat command automatically in Linux

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu

Is it possible in Linux command line to have a command repeat every *n* seconds?

Say, I have an import running, and I am doing

```
ls -l
```

to check if the file size is increasing. I would like to have a command to have this repeat automatically.

Answer (score 588, accepted):

Watch every 5 seconds ...

`watch -n 5 ls -l`

If you wish to have visual confirmation of changes, append `--differences` prior to the `ls` command.

According to the OSX man page, there's also

> The --cumulative option makes highlighting "sticky", presenting a
>   running display of  all  positions  that  have  ever changed.  The -t
>   or --no-title option turns off the header showing the interval,
>   command, and current time at the top of the display, as well as the
>   following blank line.

Linux/Unix man page can be found [here](http://linux.die.net/man/1/watch)

Comment: Nice - pitty about it not appending results to the command line

Comment: Added option to answer that allows highlighting of changes

Comment: Note that you need to escape special characters that are part of the command that you are watching, for example:

`watch mysql dbname -e \"show processlist\;\"`

Comment: watch is not installed on mac os X 10.10

Comment: `watch` can also be used with multiple commands, quoted and semicolon-separated, like this: `watch -n 5 "ls -l; echo; ps -aux"`. For discussion see https://askubuntu.com/q/595927/846840

Comment: You can install with homebrew: `brew install watch`

Comment: Beware that `watch` requires a terminal attached to the command execution environment, which is not always the case, e.g., in system startup scripts.

Answer (score 133):

```
while true; do
    sleep 5
    ls -l
done
```

Comment: `watch` also has the unfortunate side effect of clearing the screen, so sometimes the loop is useful.  Which to use depends on the desired format of the output.

Comment: I'll usually do the loop, but do it on one line.  Watch looks much better, though, I'll have to switch to that.

Comment: @MartyWallace This can be done with the command line (the while loop).

Comment: It's worth noting you can use `--differences` to have them highlighted (If you're concerned about the repainting of the terminal)

Comment: This is better than `watch`. Watch does not work for example when you want to generated random number in each invocation, e.g. `watch -n 1 echo ${RANDOM}`. The random will only get called once.

Answer (score 101):

"watch" does not allow fractions of a second in Busybox, while "sleep" does. If that matters to you, try this:

```
while true; do ls -l; sleep .5; done
```

Comment: This is useful for if you need to pipe the output somewhere (like bar aint recursive)

Comment: Thanks. This works for busybox consoles that do not have the watch command. I used it to measure the uptime of my system: while true; do uptime; sleep 1; done

Comment: FWIW on the old version of busybox (v1.11.2) I'm stuck with, there is no watch, and sleep doesn't support fractions.  But you can use sleep 1 successfully.

Comment: This is also a great way to run this in cygwin

Answer (score 47):

`sleep` already returns `0`. As such, I'm using:

```
while sleep 3 ; do ls -l ; done
```

This is a tiny bit shorter than mikhail's solution. A minor drawback is that it sleeps before running the target command for the first time.

Answer (score 20):

If the command contains some special characters such as pipes and quotes, the command needs to be padded with quotes. For example, to repeat `ls -l | grep "txt"`, the watch command should be:

`watch -n 5 'ls -l | grep "txt"'`

Comment: I was having trouble getting watch to work properly on a piped expression, but after reading this I could fix it :)

Comment: Beware that in some contexts, for instance for startup scripts, the command execution does not have a terminal attached, so commands like `watch` do not work there.

Comment: Nice additional info @dvo! I was assuming the use of a terminal at that time. Other answers may be more relevant in other cases.

Answer (score 16):

Running commands periodically without cron is possible when we go with `while`.

As a command:

```
while true ; do command ; sleep 100 ; done &
[ ex: # while true;  do echo `date` ; sleep 2 ; done & ]
```

Example:

```
while true
do echo "Hello World"
sleep 100
done &
```

Do not forget the last `&` as it will put your loop in the background. But you need to find the process id with command "ps -ef | grep your_script" then you need to kill it. So kindly add the '&' when you running the script.

```
# ./while_check.sh &
```

Here is the same loop as a script. Create file "while_check.sh" and put this in it:

```
#!/bin/bash
while true; do 
    echo "Hello World" # Substitute this line for whatever command you want.
    sleep 100
done
```

Then run it by typing `bash ./while_check.sh &`

Comment: Isn't the last & , same as writing the command without & in the end , but calling the script with & : bash ./while_check.sh &   ?

Comment: @ransh : We can run the script ./while_check.sh & so we can get the process id immediately, when we add the & in script and just run the script without & , we didn't get any process id but it will run background, as i edited we need ps command to get the process id if we need to stop the script.

Comment: If you wish, you can modify the script to `echo $!` after each background process is launched — that's the PID of the last child process launched in the background.

Comment: `echo \`date\` ` is just a poor and slightly buggy way to write just `date`. (The bug has to do with the lack of quoting of the argument to `echo`.) See also [useless use of `echo`.](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#echo)

Answer (score 8):

watch is good but will clean the screen.

```
watch -n 1 'ps aux | grep php'
```

Answer (score 7):

If you want to do something a specific number of times in `zsh`:

```
repeat 300 (command1; command2) && sleep 1.5
```

Note that `repeat` is **not** a bash command.

Comment: for bash do `for x in {1..300} ; do ` commands  `||break;sleep 1.5; done`

Comment: Your answer is a lot downvoted. Reason seem to be:  This is **not [tag:bash]**!! Please explain under which environment did this work!

Answer (score 6):

If you want to avoid "drifting", meaning you want the command to execute every N seconds regardless of how long the command takes (assuming it takes less than N seconds), here's some bash that will repeat a command every 5 seconds with one-second accuracy (and will print out a warning if it can't keep up):

```
PERIOD=5

while [ 1 ]
do
    let lastup=`date +%s`
    # do command
    let diff=`date +%s`-$lastup
    if [ "$diff" -lt "$PERIOD" ]
    then
        sleep $(($PERIOD-$diff))
    elif [ "$diff" -gt "$PERIOD" ]
    then
        echo "Command took longer than iteration period of $PERIOD seconds!"
    fi
done
```

It may still drift a little since the sleep is only accurate to one second.  You could improve this accuracy by creative use of the date command.

Comment: Thanks.. but I have 2 questions, 1- where to save that code? in other word, In which path should I put the file containing that script? that makes it run automatically?!    2- how to include php file in ( # do command ) instead of typing all my code there?

Comment: I suggest you research a bit on bash scripts so you can understand the basics of how to run them and so forth.

Answer (score 4):

You can run the following and filter the size only. If your file was called  `somefilename` you can do the following

`while :; do ls -lh | awk '/some*/{print $5}'; sleep 5; done`

One of the many ideas.

Answer (score 3):

A concise solution, which is particularly useful if you want to run the command repeatedly until it fails, and lets you see all output.

```sh
while ls -l; do
    sleep 5
done
```

Answer (score 2):

To minimize drift more easily, use:

```
while :; do sleep 1m & some-command; wait; done
```

there will still be a tiny amount of drift due to bash's time to run the loop structure and the sleep command to actually execute.

hint: ':' evals to 0 ie true.

Answer (score 1):

```
watch -n 5 'ls -l
```

Will Run`ls -l` command after every 5s

## Output :-

```
Every 5.0s: ls -l                                                                                                      Fri Nov 17 16:28:25 2017

total 169548
-rw-rw-r--  1 sachin sachin     4292 Oct 18 12:16 About_us_Admission.doc
-rw-rw-r--  1 sachin sachin      865 Oct 13 15:26 About_us_At_glance.doc
-rw-rw-r--  1 sachin sachin     1816 Oct 13 16:11 About_us_Principle.doc
-rw-rw-r--  1 sachin sachin     1775 Oct 13 15:59 About_us_Vission_mission.doc
-rw-rw-r--  1 sachin sachin     1970 Oct 13 16:41 Academic_Middle_school.doc
-rw-rw-r--  1 sachin sachin      772 Oct 16 16:07 academics_High_School.doc
-rw-rw-r--  1 sachin sachin      648 Oct 16 13:34 academics_pre_primary.doc
-rw-rw-r--  1 sachin sachin      708 Oct 16 13:39 academics_primary.doc
-rwxrwxr-x  1 sachin sachin     8816 Nov  1 12:10 a.out
-rw-rw-r--  1 sachin sachin    23956 Oct 23 18:14 Ass1.c++
-rw-rw-r--  1 sachin sachin      342 Oct 23 22:13 Ass2.doc
drwxrwxr-x  2 sachin sachin     4096 Oct 19 10:45 Backtracking
drwxrwxr-x  3 sachin sachin     4096 Sep 23 20:09 BeautifulSoup
drwxrwxr-x  2 sachin sachin     4096 Nov  2 00:18 CL_1
drwxrwxr-x  2 sachin sachin     4096 Oct 23 20:16 Code
drwxr-xr-x  2 sachin sachin     4096 Nov 15 12:05 Desktop
-rw-rw-r--  1 sachin sachin        0 Oct 13 23:12 doc
drwxr-xr-x  4 sachin sachin     4096 Nov  6 21:18 Documents
drwxr-xr-x 27 sachin sachin    12288 Nov 17 13:23 Downloads
-rw-r--r--  1 sachin sachin     8980 Sep 19 23:58 examples.desktop
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a shell alias that will watch the commands passed to it every x number of seconds. The commands can be separate arguments or separated by semicolons.

```bash
# execute commands at a specified interval of seconds
function watch.command {
  # USAGE: watch.commands [seconds] [commands...]
  # EXAMPLE: watch.command 5 date
  # EXAMPLE: watch.command 5 date echo 'ls -l' echo 'ps | grep "kubectl\\\|node\\\|npm\\\|puma"'
  # EXAMPLE: watch.command 5 'date; echo; ls -l; echo; ps | grep "kubectl\\\|node\\\|npm\\\|puma"' echo date 'echo; ls -1'
  local cmds=()
  for arg in "${@:2}"; do
    echo $arg | sed 's/; /;/g' | tr \; \\n | while read cmd; do
      cmds+=($cmd)
    done
  done
  while true; do
    clear
    for cmd in $cmds; do
      eval $cmd
    done
    sleep $1
  done
}
```

https://gist.github.com/Gerst20051/99c1cf570a2d0d59f09339a806732fd3